# pythonscript callback function using MENUCOMMAND enum?

Tags: python, notepad++

Does anyone know how to get the callback function of the pythonscript plugin to work for a menucommand? For example, i'm trying to simply have pythonscript print something to the console whenever the GOTOLINE function is used.

So in startup.py i put this code:

```
def test(args):
    console.write("goto")   

notepad.callback(test,[MENUCOMMAND.SEARCH_GOTOLINE])
```

and of course it does nothing. What am i missing?

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/docs/latest/enums.html#notification), there is no appropriate notification type for this purpose. I think you should reconsider your requirements and find another way.

Comment: Ok so i guess ONLY SCINTILLANOTIFICATION and NOTIFICATION methods can be fed to the callback function?

Answer (score 0):

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of PythonScript*

notepad.callback expects NOTIFICATION, and editor.callback expects SCINTILLANOTIFICATION.  You can't perform (currently) callbacks on menu commands.

Technically, it would be possible, but you would only get the notification that the menu item had been clicked (so no arguments), and not necessarily before the command is actually executed.  If there's really a use for this, add a post to our [forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/npppythonscript/discussion/1188885/)